# how to create a dtd for this xml?

Tags: java, xml, dtd

i have been asked to create a simple dtd for this xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<QUERY>
  <PORT>
    <NB></NB>
  </PORT>
  <BLOCK>
    <TAB></TAB>
  </BLOCK>
  <STAND>
    <LEVEL></LEVEL>
  </STAND>
</QUERY>
```

i am using java, i've never did dtd before nor do i know precisely what does it mean.
i would like some guidance if its possible, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTD is Document Type Definition, and is used to represent the structure of you XML document.  Other representations include XML Schema, Relax NG, etc.:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition

It will look something like the following (although my syntax may not be quite right):

```
<!ELEMENT QUERY (PORT, BLOCK, STAND)>
<!ELEMENT PORT (NB)>
<!ELEMENT NB (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT BLOCK (TAB)>
<!ELEMENT TAB (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT STAND (LEVEL)>
<!ELEMENT LEVEL (#PCDATA)>
```

If you look at the definition for QUERY you see it defines that it contains the elements:  "PORT", "BLOCK", and "STAND".  If you look at the definition for NB, we have declared that it should contain text (parsed character data).

Comment: thx a lot man, i think this will be very helpful to know how to start and implement it :)

Answer (score 0):

[XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) comes with a tool called [`inst2xsd`](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd) which can inspect an XML file and create an XSD for it that you can then edit/refine.  I've used it with pretty good results.

Just read the [installation guide for XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/conInstallGuide.html) and when you install XMLBeans you'll have the `inst2xsd` tool installed as well.

**edit** - just realized you wanted a DTD and not an XSD, leaving this here in case an XSD (which is very similar in purpose) could actually solve your problem anyway

Answer (score 0):

There are some DTD generators out there. Quick search yields [this](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/dtdgen.html). Haven't used it, though.

Comment: thx man, i tried it however it is not working, says classnotfoundexception when i run it from cmd line (as they mention)